# Organize WCF service to avoid circular references

Tags: c#, wcf, circular-dependency

I have three C# (.NET Framework) projects:

- A server project
- A client project
- A WCF service project

Inside the server project, I host the WCF service like so:

```
 Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/");
 ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), baseAddress);
 // Some additional logic in here, not important...
 selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), new WSHttpBinding(), 
 selfHost.Open();
 Console.WriteLine("The WCF service is ready.");
```

Where my WCF service looks like this:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public IEnumerable<ISessionModel> DoWork()
    {
        // Now I want to call methods on the server project,
        // but I can't do that because I can't reference the server project.
        // This would create a circular dependency.
    }
}
```

Here's the problem:

I can't reference server methods from the service, as that would require a circular dependency. The service is already referenced by the server because the server needs to host the service.

One solution to this would be to just define the WCF service interface WCF project, and define the implementation of that interface in the server project. But I'm not sure how to do this. As far as I know, the WCF service has to be in its own special service project.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `I can't reference server methods from the service` why would you need this? An example would be helpful

Comment: `server` may be a poor word choice. In this case, the "server" is a windows service, like, a service that runs in the background (unrelated to WCF). What I'm trying to do is allow a variety of different client applications to talk to my windows service, and I'm trying to use a WFC service to allow that communication

Comment: Like this: `various clients` -> `WCF service` ->  `Windows service (source of truth)`

Comment: It would be better to have it rather as: `clients` -> `IMyService` . `Windows service/hosting` -> `WCF Service` -> `IMyService`   (or `Windows service/hosting + WCF Service` -> `IMyService`)

Comment: That's basically what I'm trying to do. Interfaces or not, if I could combine the windows service and the wcf service into one .NET framework project, it would solve the problem. But I don't know how to tell visual studio that a WCF service is a WCF service unless it's in a special WCF service library project.

Comment: When I attempt to move the WCF service classes directly into the windows service project, I get the following exception when I then try to host it: `"System.ArgumentException: 'The value could not be added to the collection, as the collection already contains an item of the same type: 'System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataBehavior'. This collection only supports one instance of each type.
Parameter name: item'"`

Comment: Might be something in configuration either in .config files or in the code (like here  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6e6bdf93-a26d-4e21-b0a3-85e569b960a7/the-value-could-not-be-added-to-the-collection-error?forum=wcf ). Also ensure that .csproj file has same `.target` links

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Have you added the MEX endpoint to the service so that it could be referenced by the other projects?
Besides, you seem to call the Server project in WCF service project, why not use the client proxy class since they are individual projects?
Alternatively, the server project and the WCF service project are the same projects.  Do you want to find a way to host the WCF service in Server project?